# How to reshape conjoint data from wide to long?

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape, tidyr, reshape2

users,

I have received a data from a conjoint survey experiment. What I want to do is to reshape from wide to long format. However, this seems to be slightly complicated. I am pretty sure it is possible to do with `cj_tidy` (package `cregg`) but can't solve it myself.

In the survey, the respondents were asked to compare two organizations that vary across 7 **profiles** (*Efficiency* *Opennes* *Inclusion* *Leader* *Gain* & *System*). In total, respondents were presented with four comparisons. So 2 organizations and 4 comparisons (4x2). They had to choose one of the presented organization and rate them separately after choosing one.

At the moment, the profile variables are structured in this way: org1_Efficiency_conj_1, org1_Opennes_conj1 ..etc. The first part "org" indicates whether it is the first or second organization. The last part "conj", indicated the order of the conjoint/comparison, where the "conj4" is the last comparison. The CHOICE variables also follow the order of conjoint – for example,"CHOICE_conj1", "CHOICE_conj2", where =1 means the respondent chose "org1". If =2, then org2 was chosen. The RATING> variable indicates a value from 0 to 10 for each organization: RATING_conj1_org1; RATING_conj1_org2 etc..

The current wide format of the data is not suitable for conjoint analysis - what I need is to create 8 observations for each respondent (4x2=8) where the variable **CHOICE** would indicate which of the organizations were chosen (where =1 if yes; and =0 if no). In a similar way, the variable **RATING** should indicate the rating given by respondents for both of the organizations (0 to 10).

This is how I would like the data to look like:

[image]

Note please that there are also covariates such as Q1 and Q2 in the picture, they are not a part of the experiment and should remain constant for each individual observation.

Below I share 50 observations from my real data.

```
    > dput(cjdata_wide) structure(list(ID = 1:50, org1_Effeciency_conj_1 =
    > c(3L, 2L,  1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
    > 2L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    > 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L ),
    > org1_Oppenes_conj_1 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L,  3L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 1L, 3L,
    > 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
    > 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L), org1_Inclusion_conj_1 = c(2L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  2L), org1_Leader_conj_1 =
    > c(5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L,  6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L,
    > 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L,  5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L,
    > 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L,  4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L),
    > org1_Gain_conj_1 = c(4L,  4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 6L,
    > 3L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 6L,  2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L,
    > 8L, 4L, 4L, 5L,  7L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 4L,
    > 6L, 4L, 3L,  6L), org1_System_conj_1 = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L,
    > 1L, 2L,  2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L,
    > 1L,  1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    > 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L), org2_Effeciency_conj_1 = c(2L, 
    > 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L,  1L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L,  1L, 2L,
    > 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  3L),
    > org2_Oppenes_conj_1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  3L, 2L, 3L,
    > 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 3L, 1L,
    > 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L,  2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), org2_Inclusion_conj_1 = c(1L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L), org2_Leader_conj_1 =
    > c(4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L,  2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L,
    > 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L,  1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 4L,
    > 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L,  3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L),
    > org2_Gain_conj_1 = c(5L,  1L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L,
    > 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 2L,  6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L,
    > 6L, 7L, 1L, 7L,  2L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 3L,
    > 4L, 7L, 7L,  7L), org2_System_conj_1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
    > 5L, 4L,  4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L,
    > 5L,  3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
    > 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L), org1_Effeciency_conj_2 = c(2L, 
    > 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L,  3L,
    > 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L,  1L, 2L,
    > 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L,  3L),
    > org1_Oppenes_conj_2 = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L,  1L, 3L, 3L,
    > 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L,  2L, 1L, 3L, 2L,
    > 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), org1_Inclusion_conj_2 = c(2L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L), org1_Leader_conj_2 =
    > c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L,
    > 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L,  5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L,
    > 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L,  4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L),
    > org1_Gain_conj_2 = c(3L,  1L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 4L,
    > 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 1L,  1L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L,
    > 8L, 3L, 1L, 8L,  5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 6L,
    > 3L, 4L, 2L,  6L), org1_System_conj_2 = c(5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L,
    > 4L, 2L,  1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L,
    > 3L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
    > 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L), org2_Effeciency_conj_2 = c(3L, 
    > 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L,  1L,
    > 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L,  3L, 3L,
    > 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  1L),
    > org2_Oppenes_conj_2 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  3L, 2L, 2L,
    > 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L,  1L, 3L, 1L, 3L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), org2_Inclusion_conj_2 = c(1L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L), org2_Leader_conj_2 =
    > c(6L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L,  4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L,
    > 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L,  2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L,
    > 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L,  3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L),
    > org2_Gain_conj_2 = c(8L,  5L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 1L,
    > 6L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 7L,
    > 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L,  2L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L,
    > 5L, 3L, 4L,  2L), org2_System_conj_2 = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L,
    > 3L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
    > 2L,  3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
    > 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), org1_Effeciency_conj_3 = c(1L, 
    > 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L,  1L,
    > 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  1L, 3L,
    > 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  1L),
    > org1_Oppenes_conj_3 = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 3L,
    > 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L,  1L, 3L, 3L, 1L,
    > 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L,
    > 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), org1_Inclusion_conj_3 = c(1L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  1L), org1_Leader_conj_3 =
    > c(3L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L,  3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L,
    > 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L,
    > 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L,  6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 5L),
    > org1_Gain_conj_3 = c(2L,  7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L,
    > 5L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 2L,  6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 1L,
    > 2L, 8L, 5L, 2L,  8L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L,
    > 7L, 6L, 2L,  7L), org1_System_conj_3 = c(5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L,
    > 1L, 2L,  5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L,
    > 3L,  5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    > 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L), org2_Effeciency_conj_3 = c(2L, 
    > 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  3L,
    > 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  3L, 1L,
    > 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  2L),
    > org2_Oppenes_conj_3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L,  3L, 3L, 1L,
    > 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L,  3L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
    > 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L,
    > 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), org2_Inclusion_conj_3 = c(2L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  2L), org2_Leader_conj_3 =
    > c(1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L,  4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L,
    > 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L,  3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L,  5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L),
    > org2_Gain_conj_3 = c(1L,  8L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    > 8L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L,  8L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 6L,
    > 8L, 5L, 7L, 3L,  6L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L,
    > 5L, 4L, 4L,  5L), org2_System_conj_3 = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L,
    > 3L, 4L,  2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L,
    > 1L,  4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    > 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L), org1_Effeciency_conj_4 = c(1L, 
    > 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  3L,
    > 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L,  3L, 2L,
    > 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L,  3L),
    > org1_Oppenes_conj_4 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L,  2L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 3L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L,  1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L,
    > 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), org1_Inclusion_conj_4 = c(2L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
    > 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  1L), org1_Leader_conj_4 =
    > c(4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L,  6L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L,
    > 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L,  6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L,
    > 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L,  2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L),
    > org1_Gain_conj_4 = c(3L,  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L,
    > 5L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 8L,  1L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L,
    > 8L, 3L, 2L, 1L,  7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 7L,
    > 3L, 1L, 3L,  3L), org1_System_conj_4 = c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L,
    > 2L, 3L,  5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L,
    > 2L,  4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    > 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L), org2_Effeciency_conj_4 = c(3L, 
    > 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L,  1L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L,  1L, 3L,
    > 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L,  1L),
    > org2_Oppenes_conj_4 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L,  3L, 2L, 2L,
    > 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L,  3L, 2L, 1L, 3L,
    > 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
    > 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), org2_Inclusion_conj_4 = c(1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
    > 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
    > 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  2L), org2_Leader_conj_4 =
    > c(1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L,
    > 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L,  3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 6L,
    > 6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L,  1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L),
    > org2_Gain_conj_4 = c(5L,  8L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 7L,
    > 7L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 6L,  6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 8L,
    > 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L,  3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 4L,
    > 7L, 4L, 4L,  1L), org2_System_conj_4 = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
    > 4L, 1L,  4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L,
    > 3L,  2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    > 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L), CHOICE_conj1 = c(2L, 2L,  1L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 2L,
    > 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L ), RATING_conj1_org1 =
    > c(1L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 0L,  7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 10L,
    > 1L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 6L,  8L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L,
    > 2L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 7L,  3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 9L),
    > RATING_conj1_org2 = c(7L,  6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L,
    > 0L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 1L,  6L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 8L, 3L,
    > 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L,  8L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 4L,
    > 4L, 0L, 6L,  7L), CHOICE_conj2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
    > 1L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  2L,
    > 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), RATING_conj2_org1 = c(5L, 4L,  4L, 4L,
    > 5L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L,  4L, 8L, 3L,
    > 7L, 0L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 8L,  3L, 7L, 6L, 1L,
    > 7L, 0L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 7L,  7L), RATING_conj2_org2 =
    > c(0L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 0L,  3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 8L, 10L,
    > 0L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 4L,  5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 1L,
    > 2L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 6L,  2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 9L),
    > CHOICE_conj3 = c(2L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
    > 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 1L,  1L), RATING_conj3_org1 = c(4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 3L,
    > 0L,  6L, 2L, 7L, 0L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 
    > 1L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L,  6L,
    > 4L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 9L), RATING_conj3_org2 = c(7L,  4L, 6L,
    > 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 10L,  0L, 3L, 4L, 10L,
    > 0L, 4L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L,  2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L,
    > 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 8L,  10L, 6L, 8L), CHOICE_conj4 =
    > c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
    > 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L),
    > RATING_conj4_org1 = c(4L,  5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 5L,
    > 2L, 8L, 7L, 10L,  1L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L,
    > 8L, 7L,  3L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 6L,
    > 2L,  10L, 7L, 7L), RATING_conj4_org2 = c(6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 
    > 7L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 0L,  5L,
    > 6L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 1L,  5L, 7L,
    > 10L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 8L), Q7 = c(0L, 0L,  8L, 9L, 6L,
    > 10L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 3L,  0L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 4L,
    > 7L, 2L, 977L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 8L,  2L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 6L,
    > 0L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L,  5L, 977L, 2L), Q8 = c(1L, 1L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 977L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
    > 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 977L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 3L, 3L, 2L,  3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 977L, 1L), Q9 = c(4L, 8L,
    > 1L,  0L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 
    > 10L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 5L,  6L, 2L,
    > 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 0L,  977L, 7L), Q10 =
    > c(8L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 10L,  10L, 0L, 10L, 2L,
    > 10L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 4L,  0L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 4L,
    > 2L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 3L,  5L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 8L,
    > 977L, 977L, 10L), Q11 = c(10L,  9L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L,
    > 9L, 10L, 0L, 10L, 7L, 7L,  5L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 0L,
    > 7L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 5L,  2L, 2L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 10L,
    > 6L, 8L, 8L, 6L,  8L, 6L, 977L, 10L), Q12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 10L,
    > 2L, 0L,  0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
    > 0L,  0L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 977L, 10L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 0L, 966L,
    > 7L, 977L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 977L, 977L, 0L), Q13 = c(2L,  2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 977L,  2L), Q14 =
    > c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
    > 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
    > 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Q1 =
    > c(2L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 3L,  7L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 10L,
    > 5L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L,  5L, 977L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 8L,
    > 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 6L,  3L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 7L),
    > Q2 = c(1L, 1L,  1L, 977L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L,
    > 1L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 977L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L,
    > 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 977L, 1L, 3L,  977L,
    > 977L, 1L), gender = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 1L,
    > 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
    > 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    > 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), profile_age = c(5L, 2L,  5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L,
    > 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L,
    > 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    > 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L ), educ = c(6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L,
    > 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L,  4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L,
    > 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L,  3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L,
    > 3L, 3L, 4L,  5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names =
    > c(NA, 
    > -50L))
```

What I have done so far is this:

```
library(cregg) 
str(long <- cj_tidy(cjdata_wide,
                    profile_variables = c("All the profile variables"),
                    task_variables = c("CHOICE AND RATING VARIABLES HERE"),
                    id = ~ id))
stopifnot(nrow(long) == nrow(data)*4*2
```

But I'm keep getting errors. I have tried to follow the example given by the `cregg` package - but with no success. Any help is much appreciated! I am open to all possible ways, be it so through cregg package or `tidyr` for instance.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your data with `dput` however all those `>` at the start of each line makes it impossible for us to copy your data. If we have to use the data we have to manually remove `>` from each line which defeats the purpose of sharing `dput` then.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah. Should I then remove all > manually or is there other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data not being in a standard form mades this a difficult problem.  Here is a solution using the tidyr package.

The solutions involves 3 parts, dealing with the profiles, the rating and finally the rating choice.

The key to the profiles part was to pivot long and breaking up the profile names into component parts and then pivot wider for the column headings.

The rating and binary choice involved pivoting longer and then aligning the rows.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Get the  categories part correct
answer <-cjdata_wide %>% pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("org"), names_to=c("org", "Cat", "conj", "order"), values_to= "values", names_sep="_") %>% select(-c("conj"))
answer <-answer %>% select(!starts_with("RATING") & !starts_with("CHOICE"))
answer <-pivot_wider(answer, names_from = "Cat", values_from = "values") 

#get the ratings column corretn
rating <-cjdata_wide %>% select(starts_with("RATING") )
rating <- rating%>% pivot_longer(cols=everything(), names_to=c("Rating", "conj", "order"), values_to= "Choice_Rating", names_sep="_") %>% select(-c("conj"))

answer$Choice_Rating <- rating$Choice_Rating

#Get the choice correct
choice <-cjdata_wide %>% select(starts_with("CHOICE") )
choiceRate <- choice%>% pivot_longer(cols=everything(), names_to=c("Choice", "conj"), values_to= "Choice_Rating", names_sep="_") %>% select(-c("conj"))

answer$Choice_binary <-ifelse(substr(answer$org, 4,4) == rep(choiceRate$Choice_Rating,each=2), 1, 0)

    answer
```

It may be possible to simplify the above. Good luck.

**Update per Comment**
The final data frame has pairs of rows which corresponds to org 1 or 2.  I duplicated the choice so that Choice_Rating column is the same length as the Organization ("org" column).  I then compared Choice_Rating &  Organization  and setting the final value to either 0 or 1 depending on the match.
For question in the comment, A simple way is to convert the factor column to integers with `as.integer()` function, then the first factor becomes 1 and the second becomes 2 etc.  (may need to relevel in order to get the proper order).
Another option is to create a new "org" column with your factor names properly listed.
Hopefully this provides enough guidance.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried the code on the sample I shared here but keep getting this error: `!starts_with("RATING") & !starts_with("CHOICE")` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector` when running this code: `answer <-answer %>% select(!starts_with("RATING") & !starts_with("CHOICE"))`. Do you have any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict with the namespaces.  The “Select” function is a common name.  Maybe restart R and carefully reload libraries to  see if it used more than once.

Comment: I updated the tidy package and then WOW!. it worked. Thanks a lot - it does exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your time!

Comment: may I just follow up here: what if I use data with words (factors), which is standard for survey data. How does the code you provided change then? The thing is that I ran your code on a data with factor variables and the Choice_binary variable is just =0, while other variables of interest seem to work. Thanks!